# Integer solutions to $x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 = 8(x^2 + xy + y^2 + 1)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all pairs of integer solutions $(x,y)$:
>
> $$x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 = 8(x^2 + xy + y^2 + 1).$$

Let $s = x+y$ and $p = xy$. We then reduce the given equation to $2p(s-4) = s^3-8s^2-8$. Thus, $s-4 \mid s^3-4s^2-4(s^2+2) \implies s-4 \mid 4$ or $s-4 \mid s^2+2$.

What do I do from here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $(n-k)\mid f(n)$ implies $(n-k)\mid f(k)$.  This shows that $s-4\mid 72$.  Since $s$ must be even, $s-4$ can be one of the $18$ possible values.

Furthermore, we need $s^2-4p=(x-y)^2\geq 0$.  Therefore, $$0\leq s^2-4p=s^2-4\left(\frac{s^3-8s^2-8}{2(s-4)}\right)=-\left(\frac{s^3-12s^2-16}{s-4}\right)\,.$$  This shows that $4< s<13$.  There are now only $4$ cases.  All solutions are $(x,y)=(2,8)$ and $(x,y)=(8,2)$.

Comment: How do you know $s-4$ is one of the $18$ possible values?

Comment: How many divisors of $72$ are even?

Comment: There are $18$, but how do I eliminate them to get what $s-4$ is? In other words, how do I use this to solve the question?

Comment: Well, $18$ is not too large a number.  Case work should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

After your hard work, we notice that $s$ must be even $=2t$(say)

$$p=\dfrac{2t^3-8t^2-2}{t-2}=2t^2-4t-8-\dfrac{18}{t-2}$$

So, $t-2$ must divide $18$

Comment: Why must $s$ be even?

Comment: @Puzzled417, $$s^3=2\{p(s-4)+4s^2+4\}$$ which is even, $$\implies s$$ is even

Comment: Is there a mistake somewhere, as $2t^3-8t^2-2$ evaluated at $t=2$ gives $-18$?

Comment: @Batominovski, Please find the updated answer.

Comment: No, $\frac{2t^3-8t^2-2}{t-2}=2(t^2-2t-4)-\frac{18}{t-2}$.  Anyway, your hint is better than mine.  There will only be $12$ cases to work with, in contrast with $18$ cases in my hint.